# Android Non Touch Consuming Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

How would I create a dialog which does not consume touch events. Ie. I want to be able to interact with the underlying activity as normal.

```
public class LoadingDialog extends Dialog {

    public LoadingDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_dialog);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
            ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
}
```

I tried the following with no success

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
       return false;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a dialogue, you can use a view that covers the whole screen with a tint and another view that looks like a dialogue on top of the tint and pass all touch events to the view below. Remove and show the dialogue by toggling the visibility of the view.